# How to revoke write access to a collection in MongoDB but keeping readWrite privileges on all other collections?

Tags: mongodb, collections, role-base-authorization, role-based-access-control

Is there an easy way to do this?

Reading the official documentation I understood that I must create a new role with a privilege for each resource/collection I have.

The problem is that I have a lot of resources/collections and I don't want to specify all readWrite actions on the privilege of each collection.

I would love to create a role inheriting the readWrite role for my hole database and then revoke write access on a specific collection.